# dplyr loop filtering re *

Tags: r, regex, for-loop, dplyr

I using a combination of `dplyr` and a for loop to subset a database. 
I want to perform the first operation on the whole dataset. My loop with regular expression fails. What could be a solution?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(values=c("a","b","c"))
select <- c("*","a")

for (i in 1:length(select)){
  print(df %>% filter(values %in% select[i]) %>% summarise(n()))}
```

Desired result:

```
  n()
1   3
  n()
1   1
```

Comment: Ok, this works

df <- data.frame(values=c("a","b","c"))
select <- c("*","a")
for (i in 1:length(select)){
  print(df %>% filter(grepl(select[i], values)) %>% summarise(n()))}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, we can use `lapply` for each value in `select` with `grepl` to `subset` rows which match the condition

```
lapply(select, function(x) subset(df, grepl(x, values)))

#[[1]]
#  values
#1      a
#2      b
#3      c

#[[2]]
#  values
#1      a
```

You can also consider to add word boundaries to the pattern in `select` if you want to match the word exactly and don't want `"a"` to match with `"ab"` etc.

```
lapply(paste0("\\b", select, "\\b"), function(x) subset(df, grepl(x, values)))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to `paste` the `.` at the beginning and then with `str_detect` or `grepl` `filter` the rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    filter(str_detect(values, str_c(".", select[1]))) %>%
    summarise(n = n())
# n
#1 3
```

---

Or instead of using `*`, specify as `.` in 'select' as `.` matches any character while `*` implies 0 or more characters of the character preceding.

```
select <- chartr('*', '.', select)
for (i in seq_along(select)){ print(df %>% 
            filter(str_detect(values, select[i])) %>%
            summarise(n()))}
#   n()
#1   3
# n()
#1   1
```

This would work with both `grepl` and `str_detect` while the OP's original string `*` works only with `grepl`

---

Another option if we are using a fixed match with `%in%` would be to create a logical condition

```
for (i in seq_along(select)){ print(df %>% 
             filter(if(!select[i] %in% values) TRUE else values %in% select[i]) %>%
            summarise(n()))}

# n()
#1   3
#  n()
#1   1
```